# coordinate mismatch with canvas api

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make an application like open-board. For that, I am using canvas API. The problem is that the lines are drawn below the clicked point. I have already subtracted offset top and offset left but still facing the issue.
Also, one thing that I have noticed, the distance between the clicked point and the drawn figure increases as the clicked point goes farther away from the origin. Like this: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVdeK.png)

here is my code:

```js
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",(e)=>{
    let x = drawArea.offsetTop
    let y = drawArea.offsetLeft
    
    if(lineToolSelected == false)
    {
        lineToolSelected = true;
        tool.beginPath()
        tool.moveTo(e.clientX-y,e.clientY-x)
    }else if( lineToolSelected == true){

        lineToolSelected = false
        tool.lineTo(e.clientX-y,e.clientY-x)
        tool.stroke()
    }
    
    
})
```

```css
.draw-area{
    /* position: fixed; */
    position: absolute;
    top:0rem;
    left:0rem;
    height: 175px;
    width: 350px;
    background:white;
}
.draw-area-cont{
    /* position: fixed; */
    position: absolute;
    top:10rem;
    left:2rem;
    width:74rem;
    background:#eeeded;
    height: 37rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* z-index:1; */
}

#canvas{
    /* position: fixed; */
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="draw-area-cont">
      <div class="draw-area">
            <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      </div>        
 </div>
```

Comment: instead `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` try `getBoundingClientRect().top` same for `left`

Comment: Could you make your code into a runnable snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone encounters the same problem, I did this:

```js
var scale = 2;
canvas.height =  canvas.offsetHeight * scale;
canvas.width = canvas.offsetwidth * scale;
```

I don't think you even need to multiply with scale, just doing this should work too:

```js
canvas.height =  canvas.offsetHeight;
 canvas.width = canvas.offsetwidth;
```

I multiplied with scale to increase the resolution of the image.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, Its great you find the answer your self, if possible please try to explain why and how this code helps your question.